# What does eno1 and lo mean

Tags: networking

When running the following command in bash:

```
netstat -i
```

I am returned something which looks like this:

```
Kernel Interface table
iface    MTU ...
eno1     1500
lo       50000
```

I ran this command with the intentions to find what type of network adapters (hardware) I have. (should return wireless adapter + more)

I am unable to tell what these mean.

Is this the correct command for this?

Answer (score 23):

`eno1` is the onboard Ethernet (wired) adapter.

`lo` is a loopback device.  You can imagine it as a virtual network device that is on all systems, even if they aren't connected to any network.  It has an IP address of `127.0.0.1` and can be used to access network services locally.  For example, if you run a webserver on your machine and browse to it with Firefox or Chromium on the same machine, then it will go via this network device.

There is no wi-fi adapter listed.  `lspci` and `lsusb` may help you find them in the first place at which point you need to figure out why it isn't working.

Comment: lsusb returns "command not found", running lscpi I can see somewhere in the big list "Network controller: 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter (rev 03)", Does this mean it has found the adapter?

Comment: Correct - your device is a PCI device and you've found it.  You need `lsusb` to search USB devices.  You'll need to install it. It's in a package called `usbutils`.  If you type `lspci -v` it should tell you what kernel driver it's using (if any).  You may get more information on the manufacturer and model too, which should help you.

Comment: Doesnt appear to have the label Kernel Driver: next to it like some of the others do, so I assume it doesnt use a driver. I will try to install usbutils now

Comment: Sorry - my bad. You only need `usbutils` if you're investigating USB devices.  It has no drivers next to it as the kernel hasn't loaded one.  Probably because it doesn't know of your device.  You need to find out exactly what chip is inside and work out what driver is needed.  It might be a simple install of a new package or it might involve compiling the driver.

Comment: Why is `lo` loopback?

Comment: @gannonbarnett - Why not?  `lo` is the first two letters of the word "loopback".  Regardless of how the word is shortened (and nobody likes typing) someone could conceivably query why that way.  Some OSes, such as FreeBSD and JunOS  append numbers to `lo`.

Answer (score 7):

- eno1 is your embedded NIC (onboard **N**etwork **I**nterface **C**ard). It is a regular physical network interface.
- lo is your loopback [interface](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/nag/node66.html)

Your wireless adapter is not listed in your post. It will probably start with a 'w'.

To list your network interfaces, you should use `ip link`

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default 
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: em1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 5c:26:aa:aa:aa:aa brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlp3s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP mode DORMANT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether a0:88:aa:aa:a:aa brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
4: vboxnet0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 0a:00:27:00:00:00 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

In the output above, lo is my loopback[1](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/nag/node66.html), em1 is my embedded interface (of you this is eno1). wlp3s0 is my wireless lan controller (pci bus 3 slot 0), vboxnet0 is my virtualbox virtual interface.

Comment: ip link returns for me 1: and 2: in your list(diff mac address ofc). No wireless.

Comment: "nick"? My humble search approaches do not give me any results..

Comment: NIC, as in "Network Interface Card", typo.